# Hard coded Exchange name needs to work on another Exchange

Tags: web-server, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, web-hosting

**Background.**

Our Exchange setup - we have an Exchange 2003 partially migrated over to Exchange 2010. The 2003 Exchange / server is exchange.net.0000.com and our 2010 Exchange is SVER03.net.0000.com.

We have various in house websites that has contact forms also emails out reply's etc.

**Problem**

In the coding of the websites in many many places the SMTP is pointing to and using our old Exchange Server exchange.net.0000.com but we will need to complete the migration and shutdown Exchange 2003. I believe this will stop many websites from emailing out. Is there a way of adding the exchange.net.0000.com to the new Exchange or a way so when Exchange 2003 gets shutdown the websites will still be able to SMTP to exchange.net.0000.com?

Comment: Why not just change the website code to use `mail.xxx.com` and use that for **anything** which needs an email server? I set that up to point to `SVR03.net.xxx.com` before I left :-) When you move to the next version of Exchange, just change that CNAME to the new Exchange server and you'll not have to change the website code (or anything else) again.

Comment: Hiya, I did try to explain to the programmers that they should have used a generic name that could be used, but a certain somebody would have to modify lots of code as the Exchange.net is hard coded everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're ready to turn off the Exchange 2003 server create a CNAME record in your net.0000.com DNS zone for "exchange" that points to the A record for "SVER03".

Comment: Glad to help...